# Is it possible to omit references at the bottom using tufte-handout in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, tufte, lyx-layouts

I find the bottom references to be redundant, while using the `tufte-handout` layout. Is there a way, in Lyx, of omitting the references at the bottom, leaving only the citations in the sidenotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure LaTeX solution (sorry).  Simply enclose the bibliography statement in a box.  In this way all the crucial parts of `\bibliography` are still executed but typesetting is prevented.  This has the advantage, that it does not depend on implementation details of `\bibliography`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum\cite{knuth:ct:a}

dolor sit amet\cite{knuth:ct:b}

Consectetur\cite{knuth:ct:c}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\setbox0=\vbox{\bibliography{biblatex-examples}}
\end{document}
```

[image]